# ExtJS 4 Chart: Line does not care about points

Tags: model-view-controller, charts, extjs4, line

I wanna use a chart in my new ExtJS4 application.
The axes render just fine, and I get a line, too; but it does not make any sense. Here's a screenshot of my problem:
[image: Line does not care about points...]

So as you can see, I got the axes just fine and the data left of the chart should be drawn; but obviously, it doesn't really do what I expected ;-)

I tried to hardcode the data, so here's my **store**:

```
Ext.define('MR.store.ResultChartStore', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
 model: 'MR.model.ResultPoint',
 data: [
   {rings: 400, date: new Date(1970, 1, 1)},
   {rings: 398, date: new Date(1970, 1, 2)},
   {rings: 275, date: new Date(1970, 1, 3)}
 ]
});
```

The referenced **model** looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MR.model.ResultPoint', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
 fields: ['rings', 'date']
});
```

And finally my **chart** looks like this:

```
{
  xtype: 'chart',
  width: 600,
  height: 300,
  theme: 'Green',
  store: 'ResultChartStore',
  axes: [
    {
      title: 'Ringe',
      type: 'Numeric',
      position: 'left',
      fields: ['rings'],
      minimum: 0,
      maximum: 400
    },
    {
      title: 'Datum',
      type: 'Time',
      position: 'bottom',
      fields: ['date'],
      dateFormat: 'd.m.Y'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      xField: 'date',
      yField: 'rings'
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anybody spot my mistake? I just can't seem to find it, in my eyes it looks just like the examples in the docs ...

Greetz and thanks in advance
gilaras

**-------------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------**

I guess I know where the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it :-/
When I add more data to the store, the chart looks like this:
[image: My new chart]

So the problem seems to be that Ext does not "know" how to connect my points...
In my opinion it finds a point, draws a line through it and repeats it for every point specified in my store.

My chart looks like this now:

```
{
  xtype: 'chart',
  width: 600,
  height: 300,
  theme: 'Base',
  store: 'ResultChartStore',
  axes: [
    {
      title: 'Ringe',
      type: 'Numeric',
      position: 'left',
      fields: ['rings'],
      minimum: 0,
      maximum: 400,
      minorTickSteps: 1,
      grid: {
        odd: {
          opacity: 1,
          fill: '#ddd',
          stroke: '#bbb',
          'stroke-width': 0.5
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Datum',
      type: 'Time',
      position: 'bottom',
      fields: ['date'],
      dateFormat: 'd'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      xField: 'date',
      yField: 'rings',
      highlight: {
        size: 7,
        radius: 7
      },
      markerConfig: {
        type: 'cross',
        size: 4,
        radius: 4,
        'stroke-width': 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone got an idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Checkout similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991702/simple-line-chart-with-dates/8993558#8993558.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're missing an important configuration in your series. The `axis` config binds the points in your store to the axes on the chart. The Sencha documentation on this config is misleading, however; Sencha says the config takes a string when in fact it takes either a string or an array of strings. In your case, use `axis: ['left', 'bottom']`.

Second (and I'm less sure about this), you might try using the fully qualified store name in your chart config. So, `'MR.store.ResultChartStore'` instead of just `'ResultChartStore'`. Although you appear to be getting the points just fine, I wouldn't be surprised if there was some sort of side-effect.

Third, the Time axis can be a bit buggy. If you're having trouble with it, try setting it to Category and converting the date to a string. The referenced question above does state that Category axes are bugged too, but I've personally not experienced any problems with them.

Comment: Thank you very much, you just saved my weekend :-) Adding 'bottom' to the axis config solved my problem. The store however works as expected (and if I remember correctly, regarding to the docs, this is the way to specify a store using MVC pattern). 

TL;DR? Thank you :-)